# Remove PageViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have added `pageviewController` programmatically as follows. It works. However, when I try to remove with `[self.pageViewController.view removeFromSuperview];`, it does not remove it.

**Adding pageViewController**

```
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**Removing pageViewController**

```
[self.pageViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below set of instructions to remove your pageViewController:

```
[self.pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.pageViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.pageViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: sometimes removes it, sometimes not.